# Enclose expressions that include a word using a regular expresion in visual studio code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a script where I use many times the command

> console.log('anything inside')

how can I change them with regular expression into visual code or any other editor, to be like this

> if(display_comments==true){console.log('anything inside')}

where the "anything inside" and be any phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use search and replace with the following search:

```
console.log\('(.*)'\)
```

And replace with:

```
if(display_comments==true){console.log('$1')}
```

Don't forget to enable "Use regular expression" toggle next to the search input.